# Kafka Streams state store restore/recovery time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

We know that in kafka streams 'Large state implies large recovery time'.

We have deployed our application as kubernetes pod and would like to implement horizontal pod scaling (hpa). There are couple of challenges

1. Metrics on which we need to trigger pod scaling. We are planning to use CPU metrics for now. Any other recommendations ?
2. The bigger challenge is state store recovery time. After a new pod is started, it takes a quite a good amount of time for it to come to 'Running' state (15-30 mins depending on which partition/task is assigned to new pod). So, we set a very large time for readiness probe to be executed (which is generally not a good practise)

So, we are looking for ways to decrease recovery time. We don't want to use statefulset, so having state stores backed by underlying storage is out of equation here. I am also trying out streams configuration related to 'restore.consumer' but it hasn't help much.

Is there any other recommendations ?

Comment: about #2 - how many changelogs do you have ? do you have retention set on your changelogs ?

Comment: we have about 60 change logs. Majority of them has small states. A few has very large state(in GBs). regarding changelog, there are compacted topics

Comment: you can set your changelogs' cleanup policy to compact+delete, so you can delete old/out-of-date records (depending on your business requirements).

Comment: We can't really delete records from change logs.

Comment: it is a bit difficult to answer your question without more details. can you post your topology so I can get a bit more of context ? also, more details about your k8s pods could be helpful (how many pods, cpu/memory)

Comment: Can you please share reason behind it - **We don't want to use statefulset, so having state stores backed by underlying storage is out of equation here.**